# setSupportActionBar with AppCompat

Tags: java, android, interface, material-design

I was following a tutorial on how to get a Toolbar instead of a Actionbar.

This tutorial said that I had to extend mainActivity to ActionbarActivity but this class is deprecated. I google'd some and found out to use AppCompatActivity instead.

Now I'm getting the error actionbar is already provided by the mainactivity

My theme is set to custom theme with both parents `.NoActionBar`.

The error is in the onCreate method of the mainActivity when I try to setSupportActionBar(toolbar element)

Styles:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>

</style>
```

Styles v21:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Mainactivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Mainactivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3):

change `import android.widget.Toolbar` to `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in your mainActivity

Answer (score 1):

change you main activity xml :

```
<include android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>
```

to

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set your theme to @style/Theme.AppCompat instead of AppTheme. Theme.AppCompat is just the dark appcompat theme and therefor already has an ActionBar.

So change:

```
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

to

```
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

in your Manifest.

Comment: I see! now it results in the error that i need Theme.Appcombat (or descendant) with this activity

Comment: Change Theme.Material to Theme.AppCompat and you should be good